# C++ Multithreading CreateProcess. Exe running slower with more threads active

Tags: c++, multithreading, createprocess

Recently upgraded my dev machine to a i9-13900k (24 cores, 32 threads) as a result I'm looking into refactoring a test harness I utilise, the issue appears to be that there is no improvement in total time taken for tests to complete past 6 threads, which is not expected.

The setup.

```
 std::vector<std::string> tests;
 std::ifstream input("");
 for (std::string line; getline(input, line); ) {
   tests.push_back(line);
 }

  const int processor_count = 24;
  
  vector<int> thread_pool(processor_count, thread_status::thread_free);
  for (int i = 0; i < processor_count; i++) {
    thread(ThreadedFunc, ref(thread_pool[i])).detach();
  }

 auto not_all_done = [&thread_pool]()
  {
    return any_of(thread_pool.begin(), thread_pool.end(), [](int a_ThreadStatus)
    {
      return a_ThreadStatus < thread_done;
    });
  };

  while (not_all_done()) {
  }

void ThreadedFunc(int& a_ThreadStatus)
{
    while (!tests.empty() ) {


    // CRITICAL SECTION
    std::string l_Test;
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
      l_Test = tests.front();
      tests.erase(tests.begin() + 0);
    }
    // ================
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::time_t start_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(start);
    std::stringstream msg;
    msg << "Test: " << l_Test << " started." << std::endl;
    std::cout << msg.str();

    auto l_ClassID = std::stoi(l_Test);
    
    std::wstring l_wexe = std::wstring(m_exe.begin(), m_exe.end());
    LPCWSTR l_exe = l_wexe.c_str();

    std::wstring cmdArgslistSetChannel = l_wexe;
    cmdArgslistSetChannel += L" -utest ";
    cmdArgslistSetChannel += std::to_wstring(l_ClassID);
    cmdArgslistSetChannel += L" cpufactor ";
    cmdArgslistSetChannel += std::to_wstring(m_CPUFactor);
    cmdArgslistSetChannel += L" ParallelRunning CrashReporting";

    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    CreateProcess(NULL, &cmdArgslistSetChannel[0], NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
    auto diff_time = std::difftime(end_time, start_time);
    std::stringstream msg1;
    msg1 << "Test: " << l_Test << " completed. Elapsed: " << diff_time << std::endl;
    std::cout << msg1.str();
  }


  a_ThreadStatus = thread_status::thread_done;
}
```

It is appearing that past 6 threads the CreateProcess call is taking longer to execute. Would this be expected given the hardware.

Some numbers for 100 tests.

| thread | time (mins) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ? |
| 2 | 1.07 |
| 4 | 0.71 |
| 6 | 0.68 |
| 8 | 0.72 |
| 12 | 0.79 |
| 24 | 1.07 |

I was not expecting 2 threads to be on par with 24. We know from test logging the test itself is NOT taking any longer to execute, would it be the 24 CreateProcess calls fighting each other, before the exe launches.

I started writing this in perl as that's out current testing scripting lang, switched to C++ and from a one parent firing off a new thread (fork) for every test to a thread manages its work model, to the same results.

Comment: It's been documented that multithreaded performance on MS-Windows has horrible performance.

Comment: *the issue appears to be that there is no improvement in total time taken for tests to complete past 6 threads, which is not expected.*  Why you would expect the performance to scale in that manner needs to be documented in the question.  As it is, there's no way anyone can comment on the scalability of your code base - we don't know what it does and we can't see any dependencies.

Comment: This is quite normal. Modern multi-core CPUs have the ability to dynamically power off unused cores, thereby allowing them to clock up the smaller number of cores that are in use. This is beyond the ever-present and long-standing fact that there is inherent overhead in creating and running multiple threads. Why would you expect any different result?

Comment: Also this code example is so messy it is hard to tell if code is not a problem. I recommend provide full example. [mcve] is always welcome.

Comment: I don't think that general statement is accurate, @SamVarshavchik. What surprises folks who are more accustomed to \*nix when they slum it in the Windows world is that, in Windows, creating processes/threads is a very *expensive* process (relatively speaking). This is surprising because it's precisely the opposite of \*nix environments, where forking a process is an *extremely* cheap operation. But I haven't seen any evidence, much less convincing documentation, that Windows has worse multithreaded performance than any other operating system, *ceteris paribus*.

Comment: why would I expect the tests to scale, well they are running a independent exe process (yes all the same named exe) doing a different test. Task Manager is showing no resource issues with IO, CPU or RAM.

Comment: `SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST);`?  If every thread you create has a priority of `THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST`, no thread has a high priority...

Comment: Code is not a problem, removing the CreateProcess from the code and I get the expected results. I have posted what I can post, and what is required to understand the issue I'm facing.

Comment: On my old 8 core machine up to 2 threads can run at full turbo speed. Then it clocks down to not overheat. Seems only fair that your 24 cores can have 6 cores at full speed.

Comment: SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST); has not impact with this in or out.

Comment: `CreateProcess` and immediately `WaitForSingleObject` run in new thread doesn't look like a smart thing to do. It is waste of resources. Based on content `ThreadedFunc` you code should be in single thread and just organized differently.

Comment: On my old 4 core 8 thread machine, 6 threads running saw a 90%+ CPU usage and testing package time go from 42 mins, to 15mins.

Comment: *I have posted what I can post, and what is required to understand the issue I'm facing.* Let me get this straight:  **YOU** don't understand the problem, and you think posting a few lines of code is "what is required to understand the issue I'm facing"?!?!?!!!

Comment: The likely reason people are questioning your test harness is because your call to `CreateProcess` leaks two handles. If you're creating 24 processes all at once, up front, and then never terminating them, then that's not likely to cause any observable ill-effects. On the other hand, if you're doing this in a loop, then that's not ideal. It's also unclear to me why you're using processes instead of threads. The description in your question suggests that you might be mixing them up?

Comment: @MarekR why do you say that? I'm firing off say 6 threads, firing off a exe to run a test package and waiting for it to finish, as soon as one ends after one starts on the same thread.

Comment: It does not leak, I am call CloseHandle(pi.hProcess); and CloseHandle(pi.hThread); once the process exits.

Comment: You are creating threads just to do waiting for processes.

Comment: What do the processes being created do?  Do they create lots of threads? Are they IO bound?  The posted code is not the limiting step the processes being created are.

Comment: CreateProcess is launching another exe that is being tested. That process can range from taking <1sec to 30+seconds.

Comment: @RichardCritten nothing withing task manager suggests any resource issues. Is there any other tools to view IO issues?

Comment: Now when I see more code, defiantly code is main problem here. Windows API is not used in optimal way. Code is so messy that I'm not sure if there is no threading issues (races,deadlocks and so on). This waiting loop`while (not_all_done())` should be changed to conditional variable. And more .... . Do not have time to try fix this.

Comment: You don't show what `test` is in `!tests.empty()` but it definitely looks like a race condition. Specially since you lock a mutex before erasing from it which tells me it is not a thread-safe container.

Comment: @MarekR I will looking to cvs. However, removing the CreateProcess calls I can see that the threads are working as I expect them too, I've confirmed this by replacing the CreateProcess with a random sleep, and I see that as one ends another one fires off, taking as long as the sleep is. With the createProcess call each thread is appearing to be impacted, but not resource bottlenecks within taskmanager

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux that is a vector<string> however as mentioned the slowdown is not present with the CreateProcess line removed, without touching the vector

Comment: @Snappiestjack You should fix the undefined behavior (UB) to allow for a better discussion about the cause of the problem. Who's to the problem isn't caused by an interaction between `CreateProcess` and the UB? UB, by it's nature, can't be eliminated as a contributing factor to the problem until it's removed. You can't really demonstrate that it isn't the cause, other than to fix it.

Comment: Unless it was pretty clear that the actual calls to `CreateProcess` were the bottleneck (which I'd guess is unlikely) I'd just do those calls serially, put all the process handles in an array, then call `WaitForMultipleObjects` on that array.

Comment: @JerryCoffin removing the CreateProcess calls I can see that the threads are working as I expect them too, I've confirmed this by replacing the CreateProcess with a random sleep, and I see that as one ends another one fires off, taking as long as the sleep is.

I don't think creating the process is the issue, I think having 7 or more is having a impact on the process being ran, but WITHOUT showing it as a resource issue anywhere, RAM is not high, CPU is not high, disk usage is not high nothing. Is there a better tool to monitor IO than the task manager?

Comment: @Snappiestjack: Yes, Windows resource monitor does more to show I/O usage.

Comment: Windows disk IO management and Registry will NOT allow you to measure so little time correctly. I suggest to close the question.

Comment: Just to update, I've refactored the entire system, utilising thread pools and enqueueing using cvs, same results. Something within CreateProcess of the exe startup I suspect. That you cannot help with for obvious reasons.

Comment: `CreateProcess` returns before the executable has even started executing. Whatever code is in that executable doesn't affect the performance of `Createprocess`. It'll just create a process object, sets everything up so that the process can initialize itself, and then returns. It doesn't wait for anything happening in that process.